# emacs align-regexp

Tags: regular-expressions, align

I'm looking for a way in emacs to format a code like this:

```
// param1, param2, param3, param4
foo(9, 8, "bar", 3)
```

to this:

```
//  param1, param2, param3, param4
foo(9,      8,      "bar",  3)
```

I guess it should be feasible with `align-regexp` but I have troubles to express the regexp to use in this case (actually I don't really understand what the regexp is supposed to match). Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `indent-tabs-mode` set to `nil`<sup>1</sup>, the following will do most of that:

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `align-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `,\(\s-*\)` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd>

Dealing with the initial parameter is decidedly trickier. If you can guarantee the presence of a space after each comma, then you could use the following regexp along with `0` for the "Amount of spacing" question:

```
\(?:, \|^\(?://\|.*?(\)\)\(\s-*\)
```

You may prefer to use a two-step process, though. e.g.:

- `^\(?://\|.*?(\)\(\s-*\)` with spacing = `0`, and not repeating; followed by
- `,\(\s-*\)` with spacing = `1`, and repeating

You should probably elaborate on the kind of workflow you're looking for, though. Are you looking for a command to call manually? Automated alignment rules? Something to use occasionally via a keyboard macro? Other?

---

<sup>1</sup> I would recommend using the following in general:

```el
;; Align with spaces only
(defadvice align-regexp (around align-regexp-with-spaces)
  "Never use tabs for alignment."
  (let ((indent-tabs-mode nil))
    ad-do-it))
(ad-activate 'align-regexp)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @phils. Actually I usually need this in a very specific case where I want to initialize some large chunk of data in unit tests with a function that takes many parameters: having comments and parameters aligned helps a lot for readability.